# PGP_Sym_Encrypt not working in hibernate but works when using the manual insert query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, encryption, postgresql-9.4

We are attempting to encrypt a column within our database using pgp_sym_encrypt aes 256.

When i run "pgp_sym_encrypt(?,'Netswitch@123','compress-algo=1,cipher-algo=aes256')" on my DB it work successfully and the field will be inserted and encryptd correctly however when I user Hibernate:

I have added the following columntransformer to my entity

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?,'Netswitch@123','compress-algo=1,cipher-algo=aes256')")
@Column(name = "my_field")
String myfield;
```

When persisting to the db I get the error

**sqlException ERROR: function pgp_sym_encrypt(character varying, unknown, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

So I tried adding casts

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(cast(? as Text),cast('Netswitch@123' as Text),cast('compress-algo=1,cipher-algo=aes256' as Text))")
```

Still get the same

**sqlException ERROR: function pgp_sym_encrypt(text, text, text) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

(ps pgcrypto is added on the db and working as I can run the query outside of hibernate)

Comment: Try to use `@ColumnTransformer(write = "your_schema.pgp_sym_encrypt(?,'Netswitch@123','compress-algo=1,cipher-algo=aes256')")`

Comment: @Sternk Thank you for your response. Unfortunately its still giving me the same error

Comment: Are your search_path the same between hibernate and psql?

Comment: @jjanes please elaborate a bit more on this I dont really understand what that search_path is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work So I opted to create a stored procedure which does the insertion for me